# Span tag inside ng-repeat option element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hey I want to use span tag inside the ng-repeat option element to draw circle of different colors in front of the names like this.

---select Name---
first (circle or red color)
second (circle of red color)

my code looks like

```
<select ng-model="name">
   <option value="">---Select Name---</option>
   <option ng-repeat="name in namesArray">
   {{name}}
   <span style="height: 15px;width: 15px;background-color: red;border-radius: 50%;display: inline-block;"></span>
   </option>
</select>
```

All options are coming but red circle is not coming. Also if i write something inside the span tag that is also coming.

Comment: Html select elements are hard to style and change behaviors. You may want to use some 3rd party plugins like select2 or ng-select, etc to create your desired behavior.

Comment: Is there any alternative to achieve this ?

Comment: @TarafderAshekEElahi ng-select is part of angular-js only right ? How can we do that with this ?

Comment: options cant be styled(using HTML inside them or adding style) better use some other library to achieve the same.